# populating core data through JSON receiving null entries

Tags: ios, xcode, json, core-data

Trying to populate core data structure using JSON,

The code is listed below?

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();
    // Save the managed object context
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Exercises" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* Exercises = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                          error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Imported Exercises: %@", Exercises);


    NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSString *theJSONString = @"{\"key\":\"value\"}";
    NSError *theError = NULL;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONString:theJSONString error:&theError];

    Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [Exercises enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSDictionary *attributes = [[object entity] attributesByName];
        for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
            id value = [jsonDict objectForKey:attribute];
            if (value == nil) {
                continue;
            }
            [exercise setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

The code compiles and after analysing the sqlite database created, all attributes are filled with null values.

```
   NSString* secondDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Weights" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* weightsFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:secondDataPath]
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Imported weightsFromJSON: %@", weightsFromJSON);


    [weightsFromJSON enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *weightDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Weight *weight = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Weight"
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSDictionary *attributes = [[weight entity] attributesByName];
        for (NSString *attribute in [attributes allKeys]) {
            id value = [weightDictionary objectForKey:attribute];
            if (value == nil) {
                continue;
            }
            [weight setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

Edited the code above for the second entity, but fails stating data parameter is hill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're enumerating every object loaded from the JSON data on disk that you put into `Exercises` (as an aside, don't capitalize the names of local variables) but then you are not using those objects as the data source, instead you're using `jsonDict` which is hard-coded from a string and has only one key/value pair. Try changing the line

```
id value = [jsonDict objectForKey:attribute];
```

To instead say:

```
id value = [(NSDictionary *)obj objectForKey:attribute];
```

That should actually apply the data you loaded. However, there are other problems in your code - you only insert a single entity, not one for each element in `Exercises`, as well as inserting an extraneous one that you assign to `object`. Here's some code that I think may do what you're trying to do:

```
NSError* err = nil;
NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"exercisesFromJSON" ofType:@"json"];
NSArray* exercisesFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&err];
NSLog(@"Imported exercisesFromJSON: %@", exercisesFromJSON);


[exercisesFromJSON enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary exerciseDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise"
                                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [[exercise entity] attributesByName];
    for (NSString *attribute in [attributes allKeys]) {
        id value = [exerciseDictionary objectForKey:attribute];
        if (value == nil) {
            continue;
        }
        [exercise setValue:value forKey:attribute];
    }
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, it not somewhat fills in data....My JSON file has two entries, upon changing this line, the code manages to input the second (last) entries data into the core data structure, but the first entries data is still set as null...

Comment: @user2512523 I re-read your code and noticed a number of other problems, they are probably part of that.

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thank you very much, been working on this for 3 days now. Quick question if you do not mind, If i was to fill a second entity, within the same core data model using a second JSON file,... would i just duplicate this code you gave changing the entity name?

Comment: Change the entity name, and the JSON file you load, and the type and name of the `exercise` variable, that should work. Also I don't think you have to save the managed object context so many times. Maybe save at the end of the whole import.

Comment: Thanks I've added the second entity code, but receive a data parameter is nil exception, ive added the code into original question above, if you dont mind taking a peek at it. I did assume it might be that the second json file is incorrect, but everything seems fine there :S

Comment: Either your json isn't added to your target or you're using the wrong file name. Anyways, that's a totally different problem and you should approach it as a separate question.